# How to check if TAG exists inside XML with PHP?

Tags: php, xml

How do i check if a TAGname exists inside an XML file.

so if i want to get

`$dom->getElementsByTagName('error')`

and it doesn't exist, it prints out something like an error message.

EDIT:

I'm working from an API. So what happens is when a user enters an incorrect username, another XML files is loaded that contains the tag `<error>`.

However, if they enter the correct username, the XML file doesn't contain the `<error>` tag so I'm looking for a way to check if the error tag exists inside an XML.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
$dom->load( 'some.xml' ); 

$errorNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('error'); 

if($errorNodes->length == 0)
{
  message('no error nodes'); // user defined
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but if the XML that is loaded doesn't contain the <error> tag(which means it works), it still displays the message.

Comment: Huh! I don't know for sure what is going on without seeing your code and data. What I do know is that DOMDocument is not very tolerant of ill formed XML (which is easy to make). I would expect DOMDocument to choke pretty badly if it consumed some bad XML, but if not it might show an $errorNodes->length of zero for XML that contained an error tag. You could try printing out the DOMDocument to see if it's worth testing to see that the XML loaded properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
$error=false;
$AllElements = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('*');
    foreach ($AllElements as $OneElement) {
    if (($OneElement->tagName)=='error') { $error = true; }
    }
if $error {
    message('error'); // user defined
}
else
{
    message('no error nodes'); // user defined
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: I don't know why an explanation of this is needed. This makes perfect sense as is. Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
$errors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('error');
$exists = $errors->length > 0;

if (!$exists ) {
    echo 'Error message..';
}
```